# How to detect c# classes through a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a student

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CheckPropertyAttributeClass.Models
{
    public interface IRequestBody
    {

    }
    public class Student: IRequestBody
    {
        public Student()
        {
        }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(ESBJsonConverter), "NonEmptyString=>1313")]
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(ESBJsonConverter), "range(1::100)=>6; nonemptystring=>1313;length(:16)=>1114")]
        public int studentid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(ESBJsonConverter), "range(18::29)=>6; nonemptystring=>1313;length(:16)=>1114")]
        public string studentname { get; set; }

        [Range(10, 20)]
        public int age { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ESBJsonConverter), "NonEmptyString=>3064;")]

        public string iban { get; set; }


        //[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        //[JsonConverter(typeof(ESBJsonConverter), "Length(1:16)=>1194;")]
        //public long Amount { get; set; }


       public List<long> Amounts { get; set; }


        //[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        //[JsonConverter(typeof(ESBJsonConverter), "NumericString=>1194;NonEmptyString=>1313;Length(8:8)=>1114;PDateTime(yyyyMMdd)=>1207")]
        //public string DueDate { get; set; }


    




    }
    public class Teacher
    {
        [Required]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ESBJsonConverter), "range(18::29)=>6; nonemptystring=>1313;length(:16)=>1114")]
        public string Teachername { get; set; }
    }

}
```

and I have another method like this:

```
         [HttpPost]
        public void GetClassType([FromForm] FileUpload postedFile)
        {
            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                postedFile.FormFile.ContentType.ToLower();

                var result = new StringBuilder();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(postedFile.FormFile.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                        result.AppendLine(reader.ReadLine());
                }


            }
        }
```

the user upload the student.cs file and through GetClassType method I want to detect Just all type which in this file and convert the to list of objects.furthermore more I receive student.cs file from Iform file and read it through StreamReader so I have a text file but I don't know how to extract classes form the file.

Comment: In `FileUpload postedFile` what kind of files user would be uploaded? Could please include few reproducible codee snippet?